gam function output (mgcv package)
How can I improve my bam model if 3/4 gam.check plots show poor diagnosis, except for the histogram of residuals (which shows a normal distribution).

My response variable is soundscape saturation (sat1db, continuous data) and the covariates are also continuos, the main important covariate is time_day and elevation. My limitation is that I have only 1 site per elevation (total sites =8). When I add the elevation data as numeric, I get an error that memory is limited. Thus, I converted it to factor. Please advise if there is anything I could improve.
Below is my model:
gam2 <- bam(sat1db ~ s(time_day, by = elevation.factor, bs = "cc", k = 25)+
              s(elevation.factor, bs = "re")+
              s(elevation.factor, time_day, bs = "re"),
        
            knots = list(time_day = c(0.05,23.54)), #23.54
            data = mod.data.cc, method = "fREML", 
            select = TRUE, control = list(nthreads=6),
            discrete = TRUE,
            family = gaussian (link = "identity"))

I tried changing the number of basis functions (k), and eliminating the last two smooth functions to reduce complexity. After comparing these options using the AICc model comparison, the model listed above (gam2) is still the best one. However, the gam.check is not performing well.

You should include the diagnostic plots so we can what you mean by "poor diagnosis". I don't understand why you  use c(0.05,23.54) for the time_of_day knots? Even if you don't have data for those 11 observations, you'd still want the smooth to join at 00:00 and 24:00. What range of values can sat1db take? By fitting a Gaussian you are allowing values from -infinity to +infinity. If it can take such values then fixing bad diagnostic plots suggests correcting for non-constant variance or skewness/kurtosis, which is going to get complicated.

Don't use AICc - I'm not aware of any work on a small-sample corrected AIC that accounts for smoothing parameter selection; the AIC computed by AIC() for a GAM fitted by mgcv::gam() is not your standard AIC and it tries to account for having chosen the smoothing parameters from the data yet we assumed we knew these values. This term s(elevation.factor, time_day, bs = "re") is not needed; you are including a linear function for each elevation, but the by smooth already includes such linear functions.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Hi Gavin@ Thanks for your response. I cannot attach the image of my plot but it is the one generated by the function gam.check, the only plot that supports a good diagnosis is the histogram of residuals with a normal distribution. All the others (reside vs linear pred, response vs fitted values, qqplot are all over the place). In addition, the range of sat1db is between 0 and 100.  #gam #modelfit
